# how to always open a file in your project folder

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Right now, whenever I open a file in my python folder, I would have to do this:

```
f = open("/Users/LazyLinh/PycharmProjects/TimeGenGUI/mass.mas12.txt", "r")
```

Even though TimeGenGUI is my python folder, and the file mass.mas12.txt does show up under my project files. Is there a way I can always address this file as part of my python folder or find the full directory of this file, as the full directory can change if I change the folder's location?

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you do `open("mass.mas12.txt", 'r')`?

Comment: @zondo I figured it out thanks to your hint, thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

Oh thanks to @zondo's recommendation, I've figured out the problem. My `__init__.py` is in a package under TimeGenGUI, so as soon as I put the file into the folder for this package instead of parent folder TimeGenGUI, I can use `open("mass.mas12.txt", "r")`!